# Postgres - How to make a case for when it gets to certain account, it splits revenue between sales regions

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have the following tables:

```
Account | Revenue | Sales Region
--------|---------|--------------
Toyota  | 718935  | US - East
--------|---------|--------------
Safeway | 327895  | US - West
--------|---------|--------------
MLB     | 1028943 | US - East
```

&

```
Sales Region | Total Revenue
-------------|---------------
US - East    | 1747878
-------------|---------------
US - West    | 327895
```

How would I go about splitting the revenue between both sales regions when it gets to the MLB account? So instead of "US - East" getting the full $1028943, both sales regions would get $514471.50

Comment: What logic would you use to determine when an account is split between two regions?  IE, how would you know to split MLB between two regions, but not Toyota?

Comment: There is a list of certain accounts that require a revenue split. No criteria, they are just decided. So I am simply going by the name and hard coding that in.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks, removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it since your only criteria is to hard code the name for the split would be:

```
select a.region, 
       sum(a.revenue) + ( (select sum(revenue) 
                             from accounts 
                            where name in ('MLB')
                          )/
                          (select count(*) 
                             from accounts 
                            where name not in ('MLB')
                          )
                        )
  from accounts a
 where a.name not in ('MLB')
 group by a.region
```

Notice that I'm using `IN/NOT IN` on those subqueries in case you decide to split more than one account.

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7ef3a/13

Comment: I don't think you need the `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement. That can just be 2. It happens that `SELECT COUNT(*)` evaluates as 2 here because there are 2 non-MLB rows, but if you had more rows, you'd still want to divide by 2 (add half the revenue of the identified rows to each region).

Comment: @Mako212 Yes, you are right for where the number of registries is known. My solution is general in case OP wants to run the same thing in a much larger set of regions where he doesn't know the amount of it. Otherwise he could just use a simple `select sum` summing with half the value he knows excluding the one he knows right. We usually provide answers for a much larger spectrum of the OP's question not only that presented case (some times it turns out that it is only what is need, but still....)

Comment: ahh in that case wouldn't you want `COUNT(DISTINCT region)`? Since presumably in a scaled example you'd have multiple entries in each region.

Comment: @Mako212 no because you are not counting the regions you are counting the number of registries in his case coincidentally is the same number of regions.